# atof() assining 0 where needs to be a dobule

Tags: c, atof

I'm trying to write my school assignment of rpn clalculator with providing expression by command line. Ex `./calc 2 + 5 \* sin 78`

My idea is to use the `struct` data type to keep the number value or the operator type.
Here is the main to clarify all:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>


enum OPERATORS {val, PLUS, MINUS, MULTI, DIV, SIN, COS};
typedef struct value {

    double number;
    enum OPERATORS oper;
};


void get_the_onp(char *expression[], int length);


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    double result;
    int i;
    printf("Number of arguments: %d\n", argc);


    get_the_onp(argv, argc);
    //result = equation(argv, argc);

    //printf("Result is: %f", result);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the `get_the_onp()` function the `atof()` isn't working as I suspect. Here is the `get_the_onp()`:

```
void get_the_onp(char* expression[], int length) {

    int i, j, k; //iterators i for expression; j for numbers; k for operators
    char *current;
    struct value values[length];


    for (i=1; i<length; i++) {
        current = expression[i];
        //printf("%f\n", atof(expression[i]));
        if (atof(current) != 0 && current != '0') {
            //printf("Inside if: %f\n", atof(current));
            values[i-1].number = (double) atof(current);
            values[i-1].oper = val;
        }

        else{
            switch(current[0]){

                case '+':
                    //values[i].number = NULL;
                    values[i-1].oper = PLUS;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    //values[i].number = NULL;
                    values[i-1].oper = MINUS;
                    break;
                case '*':
                    //values[i].number = NULL;
                    values[i-1].oper = MULTI;
                    break;
                case '/':
                    //values[i].number = NULL;
                    values[i-1].oper = DIV;
                    break;
                case 's':
                    //values[i].number = NULL;
                    values[i-1].oper = SIN;
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    //values[i].number = NULL;
                    values[i-1].oper = COS;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    //tester
    for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
            //if (values[i].oper != val)
                printf("Operator: %d\n", values[i].oper);

                printf("Number is: %d\n", values[i].number);
    }


    return;

}
```

The output for the example expression is:

```
Number of arguments: 7
Operator: 0
Number is: 2147483636
Operator: 1
Number is: 2147483636
Operator: 0
Number is: 2147483636
Operator: 3
Number is: 2147483636
Operator: 5
Number is: 2147483636
Operator: 0
Number is: 2147483636
Operator: -2072959800
Number is: 2147483626
```

I guess that there is something with the pointer `current` but I've no idea where to follow now.

Comment: `current != '0'` is not correct. You are comparing pointer (`char*`) to non-pointer (`char`).

Comment: this here `./calc 2 + 5 \* sin 78` is not correct rpn syntax. picture rpn as a stack where numbers are pushed on the stack and whenever an operator (or function like sin) is pushed it two elements (or one in the case of sin) from the stack and pushes the result. `2 +` would not work.

Comment: Yeah I know that now after creating the `struct values[]` array I want to deal with rnp :)

Comment: `for (i=0; i<length; i++) {` --> `for (i=0; i<length-1; i++) {`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is right here:

```
printf("Number is: %d\n", values[i].number);
```

`values.number` is of type `double` (64 bit), but you are printing it as an `int` (32 bit) which invokes undefined behaviour.